# make a left outer join in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, left-join

I have an array of objects in javascript (D3) and I need to remove every object of which a certain attribute is present in another array of objects attribute,
*i.e.* a left outer join
[image: full outer join]
<sub>(source: [tazindeed.co.uk](https://www.tazindeed.co.uk/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=tutorials:personal:join-left-outer.jpg))</sub>

I managed to do it myself with 2 loops but it's quite slow.
And I don't know how to make it faster.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
            if (data2[j].attr3 == data1[i].attr4) {
                data2.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
```

> data1.length~2k and data2.length~10k

I know this has approximately been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880476/joins-in-javascript) but it's been almost 2 years and the solutions use external libraries.
I'm just curious to learn if there is a better method with javascript (or jQuery or D3, which I already use)

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a fast lookup for the values that exist in `data1`, so make a map using an object:

```
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  map[data1[i].attr4] = 1;
}
```

Then you can loop throught the items in `data2` and filter them:

```
var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
  if (!(data2[i].attr3 in map)) {
    result.push(data2[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: good answer just a note: if you must apply this kind of logic for arrays all over your app you can take a look on underscore

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not faster but more readable

```js
const left = ['1', '2', '7']
const right = ['1', '3', '5', '9']

const result = left.filter((x) => !right.includes(x))
```

Comment: note that you'll have to use [`array.some`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47642827/6908282) if you need a more complex condition to filter. Additional Reference: [`.includes()` vs `.some()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64946579/6908282)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.filter` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) or `Array.map` for that I suppose:

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    array2 = [3,4,5,6],
    fltr   = array1.filter( function(v) {return this.indexOf(v) < 0;}, array2),
    map    = array1.map( 
              function(v) {
                 var exists = this.indexOf(v);
                 return [v, (this[exists] || 'null')].join(', ');}, 
              array2),
    result = document.querySelector('#result');
fltr.unshift('<u>array1</u>');
map.unshift('<u>array1, array2</u>');
result.innerHTML = ['<b>filtered</b>\n',
                     fltr.join('\n'),
                    '\n\n<b>mapped</b>\n',
                     map.join('\n')].join('');
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is unique, you can now FINALLY use Sets to left outer join (using difference) I think as of a week ago at least using Chrome.

example - convert your arrays to sets:

```js
const frontEndLanguages = new Set(["JavaScript", "HTML", "CSS"]);

const backEndLanguages = new Set(["Python", "Java", "JavaScript"]);

const onlyFrontEnd = frontEndLanguages.difference(backEndLanguages);
// => Set {"HTML", "CSS"} 

const onlyBackEnd = backEndLanguages.difference(frontEndLanguages);
// => Set {"Python", "Java"}
```