# How to return unmatched item from two objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following objects

```
defaultObject = {
  item1: ""
  item2: 2
  item3: 3
  item4: ""
}

newObject = {
  item1: 1
  item2: 4
  item3: 3
  item4: "something"
}
```

Output which I expect is as below

```
{
  item1: 1
  item2: 4
  item4: "something"
}
```

I tried [Compare two Arrays with Objects and create new array with unmatched objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47642779/compare-two-arrays-with-objects-and-create-new-array-with-unmatched-objects).

Comment: What did you try exactly? You have objects, not arrays so you would have to loop over Object.entries

Comment: Is preserving the keys a requirement? What if the two objects have different values for the same key>

Comment: Yes,  If the two objects have different values for the same key > then it will return from `newObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
oldo = {
  item1: "",item2: 2,
  item3: 3,item4: ""
}

newo = {
  item1: 1,item2: 4,
  item3: 3,item4: "something"
}
const res=Object.entries(newo).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(oldo[k]==v||(a[k]=v),a),{});
console.log(res);
```

The `res` object is made up of only those entries (properties) that are *not* found in the `oldo` object.