# when use JS .includes() vs .some()?

Tags: javascript, include, any

**some()** - if it finds an array element, the function returns a true and does not check the remaining values.

while...

**includes()** - for all elements in the array does a generic compare and return true if it finds the match or at the first match?

When to use some and when includes?

Comment: use `Array.some()` for array of Objects, or for special condition

Answer (score 84):

`some` takes in a callback function where you can write your own logic to determine if an array contains some element which matches the conditions you wrote.

`includes` does a generic equalTo comparison on every element and will return true if at least one element in the array is equal to the value to find.

Comment: I'm wondering if includes will always operate on the entire collection or will break when the condition is true (like some).

Comment: @Sagivb.g '...will return true if at least one...'