# How do you append to an object array by searching a different array for a object and returning a different object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, indexof

Similar to a vlookup in excel. I have 2 object arrays in javascript. I want to look up an object from array #1 in array #2 and push an object from array #2 to the array #1. I want this to happen for each value in array #1. This way I can have a single array with all of the information I want in one place.

for example,

```
    let array1 = [
        {"first":"Ana","last":"Anderson","id":"0001"},
        {"first":"Bob","last":"Brown","id":"0002"},
        {"first":"Charlie","last":"Clark","id":"0003"},
        {"first":"Danielle","last":"Dunn","id":"0004"}
    ]

    let array2 = [
        {"age":"38","id":"0002","eyeColor":"hazel","hieght":"5.5"},
        {"age":"45","id":"0001","eyeColor":"brown","hieght":"5"},
        {"age":"23","id":"0003","eyeColor":"blue","hieght":"6"}
    ]
```

How do I make an array that would display the following?
I have been trying a for loop with indexof and push

```
let array3 = [
        {"first":"Ana","last":"Anderson","id":"0001","age":"45","eyeColor":"brown","hieght":"5"},
        {"first":"Bob","last":"Brown","id":"0002","age":"38","eyeColor":"hazel","hieght":"5.5"},
        {"first":"Charlie","last":"Clark","id":"0003","age":"23","eyeColor":"blue","hieght":"6"},
        {"first":"Danielle","last":"Dunn","id":"0004","age":"","eyeColor":"","hieght":""}
    ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joins in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880476/joins-in-javascript)

Comment: careful with your misspelling: `hieght`.

Comment: The approach in the duplicate is `let array3 = array1.map(obj1 => ({ ...obj1, ...array2.find(obj2 => obj2.id === obj1.id) }));`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an empty object to assign in case of no match
2. Put all new objects from array2 into a map by id
3. Iterate array1 and update items either from a map or the empty object

```js
let array1 = [
    {"first":"Ana","last":"Anderson","id":"0001"},
    {"first":"Bob","last":"Brown","id":"0002"},
    {"first":"Charlie","last":"Clark","id":"0003"},
    {"first":"Danielle","last":"Dunn","id":"0004"}
]

let array2 = [
    {"age":"38","id":"0002","eyeColor":"hazel","hieght":"5.5"},
    {"age":"45","id":"0001","eyeColor":"brown","hieght":"5"},
    {"age":"23","id":"0003","eyeColor":"blue","hieght":"6"}
];

const emptyObject = Object.keys(array2[0]).reduce((r, key) => (key !== 'id' && (r[key] = ''), r), {});
const map = array2.reduce((r, item) => (r[item.id] = item, r), {});
array1.forEach(item => Object.assign(item, map[item.id] ?? emptyObject));


console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score -1):

use a loop to iterate through array1 and for each object in array1, searching for a matching id in array2 and merge the information.

```js
let array1 = [
    {"first":"Ana","last":"Anderson","id":"0001"},
    {"first":"Bob","last":"Brown","id":"0002"},
    {"first":"Charlie","last":"Clark","id":"0003"},
    {"first":"Danielle","last":"Dunn","id":"0004"}
];

let array2 = [
    {"age":"38","id":"0002","eyeColor":"hazel","hieght":"5.5"},
    {"age":"45","id":"0001","eyeColor":"brown","hieght":"5"},
    {"age":"23","id":"0003","eyeColor":"blue","hieght":"6"}
];

let array3 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    let matchedObject = array2.find(obj => obj.id === array1[i].id) || {};
  
    let mergedObject = { ...array1[i], ...matchedObject };
    
    array3.push(mergedObject);
}

console.log(array3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of working with the index , you can prefer to create a `Map` and store the `id` as key. Then iterate the second object and check if the `id` matches wit the key of the map. If it match then you can add those properties from the second array to the object of the first array.

```js
let array1 = [{
    "first": "Ana",
    "last": "Anderson",
    "id": "0001"
  },
  {
    "first": "Bob",
    "last": "Brown",
    "id": "0002"
  },
  {
    "first": "Charlie",
    "last": "Clark",
    "id": "0003"
  },
  {
    "first": "Danielle",
    "last": "Dunn",
    "id": "0004"
  }
]

let array2 = [{
    "age": "38",
    "id": "0002",
    "eyeColor": "hazel",
    "hieght": "5.5"
  },
  {
    "age": "45",
    "id": "0001",
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "hieght": "5"
  },
  {
    "age": "23",
    "id": "0003",
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "hieght": "6"
  }
];
// create a map object
const map1 = new Map();
//iterate each element of the array and store the value in the map
array1.forEach(item => {
  map1.set(item.id, item)
});
// iterate element from array2 and check if it exists in map1, if exist then update 
// the object by 'concating' the property of the object from both array
array2.forEach(item => {
  map1.has(item.id) && map1.set(item.id, { ...map1.get(item.id),
    ...item
  })

});
console.log(Array.from(map1.values()))
```